# "Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found" when creating subscription to on-premise mailbox

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We have a hybrid Exchange deployment.  Trying to create a subscription to get updates, creates, deletes on Calendar and Contacts.

In Graph Explorer I'm logged in as an Office 365 user that has full access to the On-Premise mailbox I'm trying to access (`user@domain.com`).  I'm entering:

```
POST | v1.0 |  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://our.URL/WebHooks/Graph/GraphMessagesHook.php",
  "resource": "users/user@domain.com/contacts",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-10-23T04:00:00Z",
  "clientState": "secret"
}
```

Response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "981c0892-e6d8-490b-838d-880d8268037f",
      "date": "2018-10-20T20:32:07"
    }
  }
}
```

As a test, I created another user in Office 365 and did the same request body:

```
{
  "changeType": "updated",
  "notificationUrl": "https://our.URL/WebHooks/Graph/GraphMessagesHook.php",
  "resource": "users/userOn365@domain.com/contacts",
  "expirationDateTime": "2018-10-23T04:00:00Z",
  "clientState": "secret"
}
```

This time instead of a `404 NotFound`, I got a `403`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ExtensionError",
    "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "1f378cf0-b1ec-4b87-ba03-8dee120b748b",
      "date": "2018-10-21T20:42:46"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The `403` suggests you do not have the correct permission scopes. What scopes are you requesting and which OAuth grant flow are you using?

Comment: In Graph Explorer, I've clicked modify permissions and clicked every single one there.  In the Exchange /ecp, the user i'm logged into Graph Explorer with has full access on userOn365@domain.com's mailbox.  I'm definitely a rookie on all this stuff, especially permissions.  Is there another place i should be looking?

Comment: Selecting "every single scope" will require Admin Consent for the tenant before they'll work. You may need to double check that this consent process was properly executed. Could you expand on what you mean by "full access" and how you configured this?

Comment: Can you give me any pointers on how to verify that the consent process was properly done?  I don't have my head fully wrapped around that process.  For full access, I'm talking about on the Exchange Mailbox itself.  Running this from Exchange Management Shell:  Add-MailboxPermission -Identity userOn365@domain.com -User 'User I'm Logged Into Graph Explorer with' -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All -AutoMapping $false

Comment: Ah, I don't believe that will work. The rule is that a user can only access a mailbox that has been shared with them. Try opening the target mailbox in Outlook and sharing it with the user you're authenticating with.

Comment: So opened userOn365@domain.com in Outlook, clicked share calendar, chose userLoggedIntoGraphExplorerWith@domain.com from the directory and choose full details.  In addition, I right clicked on userOn365@domain.com's calendar>properties>permissions tab and set userLoggedIntoGraphExplorerWith@domain.com to Owner.  Still getting the 403 "message": "Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Forbidden; Reason: Forbidden]" error.

Comment: Can you add the token you're getting back to your question? It sounds like something is missing from the scopes. Are you able to do this when both sides are Exchange Online users?

Comment: the 403 is when both sides are on exchange online.  i get a 404 if i try to go from on-prem to exch online.  I'm using graph explorer - not sure how to find the token i'm getting back - is there a way to pull that somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Graph API for on premise mailboxes is only a subset of the cloud functionality.

Don’t think they implemented subscriptions for on-premise mailboxes. That would be pretty resource intensive on both sides.

To my knowledge they just proxy the request to your local Exchange (which is configured to accept the Azure tokens). For rest calls that is easy, for subscriptions the routing would be difficult.

Comment: I'm wondering if that's the case as well, to rule out an error on code for creating a subscription, I created a test user on office 365 and attempted a subscription...  Not a 404 now but a 403 forbidden.  I've granted full access to the exchange mailbox and granted every permission available in graph explorer.  Wonder if there's still something wrong with my code