# Are event subscriptions available in an office-365 hybrid deployment

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, exchange-server

We have a customer who has a hybrid o365 deployment with all of their calendars/mail boxes on-premise. We have successfully queried the Graph API for the user calendars. However when we attempt to create a subscription to a user calendar we have the following 404 error...

```
{\"code\":\"ExtensionError\",\"message\":\"Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: The mailbox is either inactive, soft-deleted, or is hosted on-premise.]\
```

The error seems to strongly indicate that the subscription is not supported due to the mailbox still being on-premise. However, I cannot find documentation that definitively states that subscriptions are not supported in hybrid environments. I need a definitive statement that I can return to the client.

I found an older post on SO where that conclusion was hinted at, but again, nothing definitive...

["Status Code: NotFound; Reason: Not Found" when creating subscription to on-premise mailbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910327/status-code-notfound-reason-not-found-when-creating-subscription-to-on-prem)

I've also read the documentation on Graph support for hybrid deployments and could not locate my "smoking gun".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support

Is there documentation regarding this that I have simply overlooked, or can a MSFT SME comment in this regard?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question somewhere else, that you can share here? I have the same problem.

Comment: No definitive answer but almost certainly this is not supported in hybrid environments. We communicate this to our client.